# Twig function navigation in PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, ide, twig, phpstorm

I have been successfully using `space + left click` navigation from within my twig templates to open function, filter definitions.

E.g.

```
{{ somefunction() }}

-->

new \Twig_SimpleFunction('somefunction', ...
```

For some reason this has stopped working. Strangely autocomplete still works though.

Comment: What OS? Under linux / phpstorm & symfony2 plugin 0.12.116 it is ctrl - left click for me. Maybe check that the expected keymapping still exists.

Comment: did you recently update phpstorm or the sf2 plugin ?

Comment: I did update attempting to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the Checkbox "**Enable Plugin for this Project**" in the PHPStorm Stettings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Symfony

Make sure the Twig-Plugin ist installed.

Restart PHPStorm, Done.

Comment: Note that starting from PHPStorm 2021.1 you can find the "PHP"-node in the settings in the root directly (not under "Languages & Frameworks" anymore).

Answer (score 0):

### Go to declaration and its type

[JetBrains PhpStorm Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_declaration)

TL;DR: Keep pressing `Ctrl` and hover over function/filter and `left click`.
This is not limited to twig templates and can be used throughout all PhpStorm.